# php - CodeIgniter Error 1054

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I'm trying to insert data on my table however this error pops-up
A Database Error Occurred

> Error Number: 1054 
>   Unknown column '$blog' in 'field list'
>   INSERT INTO `blog` (`$blog`) VALUES ('')
>   Filename: C:/xampp/htdocs/ci3/system/database/DB_driver.php
>   Line Number: 691

Here is my code on my Controller.

```
public function posting(){
$name = 'Jio';
$time = date('F d,Y');
$slug = url_title($this->input->post('title'),'underscore','true');
$blog = array(
  'title' => $this->input->post('title'),
  'short_desc' => $this->input->post('description'),
  'post' => $this->input->post('article'),
  'slug' => $slug,
  'author' => $name,
  'date' => $time
);

$this->BlogModel->addPost('$blog');
redirect('admin/blog/createpost');
}
```

Here is the code on my Model

```
public function addPost($data){
$this->db->insert('blog',$data);
}
```

Note: My Model has been loaded on the constructor of my controller.

Comment: `$this->BlogModel->addPost($blog);`  try this

Comment: Silly me. Thanks for the help @VivekSingh